# What is the difference between a conditional model and just having multiple models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, generative-models

Say I have a labeled dataset that I want to create a generative model for, like a Generative Adversarial Network or a Variational Autoencoder. What do I gain or lose by making my models conditional (i.e., feeding the labels into the model along with the actual data) over just creating multiple models, one for each label?